# TimeInterval function setting with UIPicker

Tags: iphone, uipickerview, nstimer

I have following part of code. It is executing when user will select any time interval from UIpicker.

```
if([[arrayNo objectAtIndex:row] isEqualToString:@"1 minutes"])
    time=60;

if([[arrayNo objectAtIndex:row] isEqualToString:@"5 minutes"])
    time=300;

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(updateMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I am defining two time in UIPicker "1 minutes" and "5 minutes". Suppose once user will select "1 minutes" then function "updateMethod" will be call after 1 minutes of time period. But let suppose user again change his time to "5 mnutes" from UIPicker. Then what will happen? Is timer will be set to "5 minutes" OR it will be set to "1 minutes" and "5 minutes" both?

How will I design code to set function calling for one time only?
Help me in it concept?

Answer (score 0):

Every time this is called, you will schedule a new timer, so in your example, you will get both.

I generally discourage `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:...` for basically this reason. You now have no way to cancel your timer. You should create an `NSTimer*` ivar like this:

```
@interface ... { }
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSTimer *updateTimer;
@end

@implementation ...
@synthesize updateTimer=updateTimer_;

- (void)setUpdateTimer:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
  if (aTimer != updateTimer_) {
    [aTimer retain];
    [updateTimer_ invalidate];
    [updateTimer_ release];
    updateTimer_ = aTimer;
  }
}
...
self.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimenterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(updateMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

This will automatically clear the old timer whenever you set the new timer.

Do note that basing logic on UI strings (@"1 minutes") will break localization if you ever want this to be translated into other languages. Instead, you would normally either just use `row` to decide the value, or you would add small dictionaries or objects to `arrayNo` that would hold the label and the value.

Comment: thanks for post.I am getting error message on "self.timer". sorry I am new in iphone app.

Comment: I accidentally declared updateTimer as an ivar rather than a property. Fixed in the above code.